# How do I make a read only cell editable in a gridview control in asp using vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, visual-studio-2019

Hi me again with another question.

I'm using VS2019 and VB on an aspx page. I have a gridview that has Edit enabled.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y0o4.png)

When a user clicks the EDIT link Progress % and Comments become editable.

What I want to do is make the Goal be editable if Approved is set to No.

How can I do this?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdgoals" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="DS1" Height="225px" Width="1001px" BorderColor="#003960" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" DataKeyNames="goalid" EmptyDataText="No goals found." Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Strikeout="False" ForeColor="#00AD86" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AllowSorting="True" style="margin-right: 21px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="goalid" HeaderText="goalid" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="goalid" Visible="False" />
                <asp:CommandField EditText="EDIT" ShowEditButton="True" ShowHeader="True">
                    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#003960" />
                <ItemStyle Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#006EAA" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="#003960" Width="20px" />
                </asp:CommandField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="goaltext" HeaderText="Goal" SortExpression="goaltext" ReadOnly="True" >
                    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#003960" />
                    <ItemStyle BorderColor="#003960" Width="250px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" DataField="type" HeaderText="Type" ReadOnly="True" >
                <ItemStyle Width="70px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="progress" HeaderText="Progress %" SortExpression="progress" >
                    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#003960" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="#003960" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="20px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="comments" HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="comments" ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
                    <ControlStyle Height="400px" Width="240px" />
                    <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#003960" />
                    <ItemStyle BorderColor="#003960" Width="250px" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="approved" HeaderText="Approved" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="approved" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#006EAA" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

I have searched online looking for answer but haven't found anything.

Comment: Hum, I going to suggest that you drop the built in GV edit. 

It can be "somewhat" more work, but perhaps you consider just a edit button, and when clicked you hide the gv, show a div with the information laid out as simple controls in the page. When you hit save, you hide that div and show the GV. This gives you oh so much more control over such little issues.  If you open to this idea, I can post how to do this.

Comment: A recommendationf to future maintenance and readability, a bit of your code is duplicated in the gridciew markup. Much of that could be moved into a headerstyle tag that covers the whole gridview and removes the redundancy. You can still do one off changes inline where needed, but you could cut the size and complexity of your gridview down significantly

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so how much extra code is it to simple drop in a "plain jane" button to click on and edit?

It not much!!!

You do have to bear the cost/time of building a form layout for the one row, but at the end of the day:

this tends to be "easy" for the users.

You can also then move the row delete button to that "form layout" area for editing one record. (this means you don't need a delete record button on the GV - not a huge deal, but that means users have to make a "bit more" effort to delete a row of data if that option is desired).

However, the "why" of having a detail edit layout?
You can now have MUCH more control over your logic (such as the rule to allow what to edit, change or even "enable" based on other values. And such code is clean easy server side code.

And this allows far more code logic into the editing of that data. (required fields, formatting, all that stuff.

Best bonus feature?

Such a approach now ALSO allows adding of new records in a MUCH more user friendly way, since now the "edit" area you build ALSO can be used as the "add new" record area. (so, you save having to write separate code for edit and adding - the one solution does both). And this also means the end user has the "same" experience when editing existing, or adding new - it shortens the user learning curve.

Now, about the only downside?

Well, when starting out, those wizards can be a real gift horse. And I still after all these years often use the wizard(s) to create the GV.
however, I THEN clean it up a bit, and remove things from the page.
(such as removing the datasource on the page).

And the other tip?

If possbile, build a few "helper" routines. They can be used over and over.

For example, I became VERY tired of having to type in code with a row of data, and then "please fill out" those controls on the page with that data.

Then after done, we have to take that those controls, and send back to the database. We do this "over and over". And the code to do this is darn near the "same" over and over. So, then, why not write one sub routine that can do this for ANY page we work on!!!

So, here is a working approach.

for the GV, then the markup becomes rather clean - just some fields.

Say, like this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="40%"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
    CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit"
                    CssClass="btn myshadow"
                    OnClick="cmdEdit_Click"
                     />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note a few things in above:

If we don't use width, or use 100%? The GV will expand to the WHOLE page - it is what we call "responsive".

I assume that you have bootstrap installed, and most projects do (by default).

The result is a "very" nice grid, and the fonts + spacing and layout is "tweaked" by bootstrap. The result is quite nice.

Code to load the GV is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData()
    End If

End Sub


Sub LoadData()

    Dim strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
    GridView1.DataSource = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Note the "helper" routine MyrstP. I use this "over and over" everywhere.
(I'll post that at end of this post).

So, I removed the Sqldatasourc1 from the page. I find that you obtain/enjoy MUCH more control over the code. (but, if you don't have a helper routine, then setting up a query + connection and all that jazz? Then you might as well just stick with the wizard generated SqlDataSource on the page. But, you find over time that using code behind is a "less effort" choice, and one that gives you far more control (say to filter, or do other things).

*And note the table hover (you get a "nice" row hover effect), and note the table-striped. That gives you a nice alternating row shade - and you do not need a messy "alternating" template.*

[image]

So far? We have a VERY clean markup, and so far VERY little code has been written.

Now, not the button we dropped into the GV. That is a plan jane asp.net button. We don't need to use "speical" commands, "speical" code or anything. Just a good old fashioned button and button click.

However, do note that we have a click event for the button. Normally, I often just double click on a button, and then a code behind stub is created, and we are jumped to the code behind editor.

however, since the button is "nested" in a GV, then we can't double click on that button to create a event.

So, flip to markup. And in markup type in

```
OnClick=
```

WHEN you hit the "=", then intel-sense should pop up and gives you the option to create the event. (since we can't use double click on button to do this).

So, it looks like this:

[image]

And thus the code is for button click:

```
Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer
    Dim intPK As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    Dim cmdSQL = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID")
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intPK
    Dim rstHotel As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)

    ViewState("PKID") = intPK
    fLoader(EditRecord, rstHotel.Rows(0))

    GridView1.Visible = False       ' Hide GV
    EditRecord.Visible = True       ' show edit area

End Sub
```

Again, note the small amount of code.

The button click thus:

```
 we get GV row
 we get GV row PK database ID (using datakeys feature)
 we pull that data row into data table
 we call the floader() routine that takes ONE row, fills out controls.
```

the resulting effect is thus this:

[image]

And our helper MyRstP routine is this:

```
Public Function MyrstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand,
                       Optional cmdOnly As Boolean = False) As DataTable
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using mycon As New SqlConnection(GetConstr)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = mycon
            mycon.Open()
            If cmdOnly Then
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Else
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function
```

I'll post more code from above (later this evening)., and say have some "conditional" code. Say if the hotel not active, we can't edit description.